# eve framework send custom response

Tags: python-3.x, eve

I added a custom auth class that `return` if a predefined control fails.
If it fails, the client will receive this answer: `{"_error": {"code": 401, "message": "Please provide proper credentials"}, "_status": "ERR"}`

I would like to know if it is possible to customize the above answer.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flask's `errorhandler` decorator to intercept the 401, like so:

```
@app.errorhandler(401)
def my_own_error_msg(err):
    return make_response("Hello, this is Devo.", 401)
```

See [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response) and [Custom Error Handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) for more info

Comment: I would like to customize the message because I need to send to the client a specific warning...

Comment: I updated the answer. It is actually possible and very easily so, just use flask's own magic.